# Does the Weapon Master feat grant you a fighting style?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, fighting-style

Does the Weapon Master feat grant you a fighting style?

I've heard this, and even seen this somewhere, but I cannot find the right source/book for this. Maybe my PHB is just outdated?

---

My confusion was from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nQUed1FkHA) and the feat's description from third party content that listed a different weapon master feat and did not clarify that it was homebrew.

Comment: Relevant: As of July 2020, the latest [Feats UA](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_Feats.pdf) does include one called "Fighting Initiate" (with a prereq of proficiency in a martial weapon) that grants one fighting style from the fighter's list of options.

Comment: With the release of Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, the Fighting Initiate feat is now official rather than UA

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Your PHB is correct: Weapon Master does not grant you a fighting style

The [Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/weapon-master) feat (PHB, p. 170) grants you:

- +1 to your Strength or Dex, to a max of 20.
- proficiency with four simple or martial weapons of your choice.

There's no mention of acquiring a fighting style. Modifying the feat to include one would be introducing [homebrew](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnDHomebrew/comments/8g8ses/5e_weapon_master_feat_rework/) to your game.

**No other official feats currently allow a PC to learn a fighting style, either.**

---

**Note**: One possible source of your confusion (suggested by [linksassin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/48759/linksassin) in the comments) could be the similarly named [Great Weapon Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/great-weapon-master) feat (PHB, p. 167) - which is different from the Weapon Master feat, but also doesn't grant a fighting style - and the name of the [Great Weapon Fighting fighting style](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#FightingStyle).

The Great Weapon Master feat and the Great Weapon Fighting fighting style work well together for obvious reasons. There is no overlap in the benefits they provide.

Comment: I have seen a blog post arguing that it _should_ grant a fighting style to be worthwhile. I agree, but I cannot find the link. The querent might have seen the same post.

Comment: There could also be confusion with the _"Martial Adept"_ feat which grants two **maneuvers**. While not the same as the "Fighting Styles" feature, I could see people swapping names without thinking.

Comment: In my case, the confusion is caused directly by certain websites that share plain misinformation regarding the feat, such as: *"Weapon Master.
Increase your Strength or Dexterity by 1, to a maximum of 20.
You gain proficiency with any four weapons of your choice; OR you gain a fighting style of your choice from the Fighter's list."*